# HTTP Error 403 Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, cms

Здравствуйте. В CMS создается объект (таблица в бд, папка и несколько файлов на сервере) и когда визуально хочешь его отредактировать, то загружается пустая страница. В логах апача:

```
cloudme.com: 127.0.0.1 [16/Jan/2015:01:59:42 +0300] "GET /admin/objects/content.id.110.html HTTP/1.1" 403 - "http://cloudme.com/admin/tree/index.pid.1.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
```

Вот файл .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset WINDOWS-1251
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex cms.core.php index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /cms.core.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(thumb.*)$ scripts/thumb.php?$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(imagick.*)$ scripts/imagick.php?$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(error.*)$ scripts/error.php?$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*)$ /cms.core.php [QSA]

<Files ~ "\.(tpl|conf)$">
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, стоит копать в сторону настройки пользователей и прав для них. Вероятно, что у пользователя сервера нет доступа к просмотру файлов, которые создает админка.